# Not working Using file_get_contents to POST data

Tags: php, http-post, file-get-contents

I try to get content from https://www.freeformatter.com. I want to get POST data from that site. but my PHP script not working.

```
$data = array ('htmlString' => '<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-8">&encoding=UTF-8', 'indentation' => 'THREE_SPACES');
$data = http_build_query($data);

$context_options = array (
    'http' => array (
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n",
        'content' => $data
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($context_options);
$result = file_get_contents('https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html', false, $context);

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Help by voting and accepting answer if its work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not worked. Reason is freeformatter.com is not allowing to give API or POST call. They always return you view-source of html page. This is allow to use from UI but not by API call. I tried with CURL post also. its gives return back view-source of html.

Here is code you can try this works well with different

```php
<?php
$data = array ('htmlString' => '<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-8">&encoding=UTF-8', 'indentation' => 'THREE_SPACES'); 
$data = http_build_query($data);
$context_options = array (
        'http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header'=> "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                . "Content-Length: " . strlen($data['htmlString']) . "\r\n",
            'content' => $data
            )
        );

$context = stream_context_create($context_options);
 $result = file_get_contents('https://en99otyaenia.x.pipedream.net', false, $context);
 var_dump($result);
```

Code doesnt have any issue. Issue is with URL.